# How to deploy a python chatbot

Tags: python, chatbot

I am a beginner of chatbot, I have developed python code to do pattern match from an intents.json file. code works fine and can answer questions.

But how to embed this python file and intents.json file into a site as a chatbot widget? Appreciate if any good tutorial for end-to-end chatbot project. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers do not run Python, so you would need to write an API. You can use Flask to do so fairly easily. Flask's tutorial is excellent.

An alternative would be to write a Javascript version that can run in the browser. This avoids the Flask server, but then people could easily jack your chatbot.